# laravel relationship filter query

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

This is a strange one.

What i need to do is filter out any many to many items that are already attached to the current item

So lets say `box` and `tool` for examples sake, I need a laravel query to show all `tools` that are not associated with the current `box`. The problem is that the tool can be associated with a different `box` as well so even if I can filter the relationship i cannot guarantee that another relationship might still make the `tool` seem like its not already associated.

```
$data = Tool::select(
    'tools.id',
    'tools.name', 
    'tool_box.box_id')
->distinct()
->join('boxes', 'tools.id', '=', 'tool_box.tool_id')
->where('tool_box.box_id', '!=', $id)
->get();
```

This is more or less what i was currently going with, it can filter some of the items but if a tool is associated with more then one box, it fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you all tools that isn't in your current box:

```
$data = Tool::select(
  'tools.id',
  'tools.name', 
  'tool_box.box_id')
->distinct()
->join('tool_box', 'tools.id', '=', 'tool_box.tool_id')
->whereNotIn('tools.id',
    DB::table('tool_box')
    ->join('tools', 'tools.id', '=', 'tool_box.tool_id')
    ->where('tool_box.id', '<>', $id)
    ->lists('tools.id')
  )
->get();
```

Comment: You were close, the only issue was that the `->where('tool_box.id', '<>', $id)` needed to be `->where('tool_box.id', '=', $id)` since it needs to create an array of values to ignore. Also since `tool_box` is a pivot table, with this ignoring the tools by ID there is no longer any reason to join. Thanks for the help this really helped me understand more of Eloquent.